# HOW TO debug Google App Engine web application locally in Pycharm?

Tags: debugging, google-app-engine, web-applications, pycharm, webapp2

I'm taking this [Udacity class](http://www.udacity.com/overview/Course/cs253/CourseRev/apr2012) which requires us to use the google app engine.  I am using Pycharm as my python IDE. When I edit python file and then go to http://localhost:portnumber, I get "Sever Error". How do I find out what is causing the error in my python file? I can debug a normal and local python file.  However, this is a web application. Can I debug it locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyCharm has built-in [App Engine support](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/google-app-engine.html), including [Debugging](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-app-engine-server.html).